# Is it possible to prevent HTML5 data attribute action from triggering with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm asking this question only for **learning purpose** as I solved the problem even before writing this, but maybe you'll point out something useful for someone else.

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and its [modal lib](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) and here's what my code does. We open a modal, ask the user to input some json and then, the user press a "compute button" to compute the data and then the modal closes because of the `data-dismiss`.

I just want to know if it's possible to prevent an action triggered by the html `data-dismiss` attribute using jQuery, javascript or something else.

Here is the HMTL code for the modal:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="source_modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Manually insert the data</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea class="source_input">Insert your data here</textarea>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <a href="#" class="btn action_clear">Clear</a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary action_compute" data-dismiss="modal" href="#"><i class="icon-fire"></i> Compute</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the last button (compute button) has `data-dismiss="modal"`

So basically, there's a `try catch` function attached to the `action_compute` class of the anchor.

See this jQuery code:

```
// compute graph with json input
  $('.action_compute').on('click', function(event) {
    try
    {
      var json = JSON.parse($('.source_input').val());
      create_graph(json);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      txt="There was an with your json data.\n";
      txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
      txt+="you can try to validate it with JSONLint. You may also leave the textarea blank for default behaviour";
      alert(txt);
    }
  });
```

Is it possible to prevent the action triggered by `data-dismiss`?

Note:

- The Twitter bootstrap provide a jquery method to close the modal so I removed `data-dismiss` and I dismiss the modal using `$('#upload_modal').modal('hide');` only if I get to the end of the try so it does what I want.
- The jQuery `event.preventDefault();` doesn't stop the dismiss action when placed on the first line of the `catch(err)` jQuery code ;)

Comment: As it seems for me `event.preventDefault()` has no relation to `data-dismiss` or a same sort of stuff. It is the method defined by the DOM specification and it's intention is to prevent default consequences of DOM-events. Whereas in your case modal is closed because of some inner logic in the Bootstrap's JS (some handler is attached to elements with `data-dismiss` attr). That is, you can't define our own function, call it and then try to exit from it with the `event.preventDefault()` call

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding a listener to prevent the execution of the `hide` method.

```
$('.modal').one('hide', function (e) {e.preventDefault()});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Place this inside the error catching section.  As long as the click event is handled before the call to `hide()`, this should work.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/fkUHe/)

---

Since you did say the question was for learning purposes, I'll add some additional info here on the architecture of Bootstrap plugin events.

Many of the Bootstrap plugins include both "before" and "after" events.  The "before" events, in this case **hide**, are triggered and propagate up the DOM *before* any of the essential actions of the associated methods have been executed. When execution is returned back to the originally triggering methods, the first thing that happens is a check to see if the action has been cancelled:

```
if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
```

Hence, any event listener which calls `e.preventDefault()` will effectively cancel the action.  Simple and as you would expect.

Any well implemented jQuery plugin which triggers events should have this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for this fabulous answer and for taking the time to add the great additional info, this is surely the best answer I could have. Works exactly as expected!

I even learned we can add additional ressources easily such as Twitter Bootstrap right into jsfiddle :)

Thank you again, much appreciated.